# Was this out of line?

Tags: discussion

[I answered a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7732/656).

I included a picture.  The picture may not be entirely SFW, but is not pornographic or offensive (in my sole opinion).

I debated about including the picture for a bit, and eventually landed on, "Yes, it should be ok."

I wouldn't have landed there had Threepio been female, or had he had a skin covering, but in this case, I judged it ok.

Is there a guideline I'm forgetting that governs such things, or is it purely up to the individual to make these decisions?

Secondarily, did I make the right decision, or should I remove the picture?

Comment: Posting this as a comment, since it doesn't address the guideline issue you raise, but the picture is completely harmless, and, unless I miss my guess, an official/canon photo (I'm assuming it isn't a doctored image). The only reason there seems to be any question is because of the innuendo in your answer, which seems suitably "PG" to me.

Comment: @Beofett: the image isn't doctored, and it WAS released as an official card - the picture was taken as a joke, and someone flubbed during the screening process for the cards.

Comment: Heh I assumed it was just a really weird angle and unintentional "wardrobe malfunction", in a "does this outfit make my [hips] look big" type of way.

Comment: I wouldn't have added it. I would have linked to it (with explanation / warning) so that people have the *option* of seeing it. As it is, they're confronted with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back in my moderating days I had a maxim for users who would ask me 'is it suitable to post xyz':

> If you have to consider the suitability of a post for more than a few seconds, then it's probably not suitable.

I think the current incarnation of your answer, with the link giving fair warning that it might not be suitable for some people (which, of course, will encourage others to view it even more), is spot on.

*Disclaimer: I didn't see anything wrong with the picture, but I still might have thought twice about posting it, too.

Comment: I don't think anyone was offended, at all, but your rule of thumb is a good one.

Answer (score 8):

To be honest, I couldn't even tell what was there until I thought about why you would think it would be a problem: all that gold blends in.

But does it really make or break your answer to have that inline with the risk of someone getting offended by it? Why not just link to it?

Comment: +1 for "just link it". I personally wasn't offended but I can see how that is a bit problematic with others

Comment: For the record I am not offended by it.  I recognize it for what it is an artifact that looks inappropriate.  But if someone saw it over my shoulder at work I could see HR not seeing it the same way.

Comment: I second "just link it"

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a problem with that picture, but then I'm not easily offended. On the other hand, its inclusion, as your answers stands, looks a bit sophomoric.

I can't quite tell from your description whether that critically-placed metal rod is there on purpose or not, nor whether the picture is an official one. Sourcing the picture would be nice; and then, as Mark suggests, you might find it more natural to link to the picture rather than inline it, which would sidestep the issue.